# What are the benefits of client-side XML/XSLT page?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, web, client-side

Could you please describe the benefits of having client-side XML/XSLT page? What are the benefits over server-side XML/XSLT, etc?

The main point looks to me to unload the server side..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Lighter load on server
- (possibly) less network traffic
- The one xml-type http resource can be used for both human inspection (via browser hosted transform) and for machine consumption.

A good example is the World of Warcraft character database. A person can view his character information in convenient html format, and a game addon can leverage the raw data. Both observers are reading the same xml file.